# Problem with Django styling

Tags: python, django

Hi new to django but I'm having issues with the stylesheets (CSS) of pages.

my settings.py contains

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)
```

please can someone help me shed some light on what I need to do to get the CSS styles working in my templates

Thanks

Comment: Using the dev server or in production?

Comment: dev server but was hoping to make use of import os.path to make things relative

Comment: Please UPDATE your question with the missing information.  Don't add comments to a question which You own.

Answer (score 1):

The templates setting is just for aiding when you're selecting a template file for rendering in your view handler.

If you want to serve files, such as CSS, see [how to serve static files with Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/howto/static-files/), which is the easiest way. The best way, however, is to configure your server to, for the CSS (and other static files) requests, serve the files himself instead of handing the request to the Django handler.