# Apache not serving django admin static files

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Let me thanks you guys at the Stack Overflow community for helping me with various Django and Apache (with mod_wsgi) errors. I've asked about 5 related questions so far and now I'm getting closer and closer to getting my content out on a production site!

So I know there are many similar questions about this and I have read a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179453/django-and-serving-static-files) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043868/problem-with-django-styling) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402185/serving-static-files-while-running-djangomod-wsgi-on-apache-2-2) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271731/djangos-admin-pages-are-missing-their-typical-formatting-style-have-i-set-it-u) [serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found) [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073916/problems-linking-to-static-files-in-django-1-3) [media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396552/problem-applying-css-in-django-with-static-files-app) [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409920/django-static-files-from-app-directories) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833675/django-admin-has-no-style) [Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687136/static-media-fails-to-load-in-django).

I read about `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT`, the (soon to be obsolete) `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`, and setting a `Alias /media/ ...` in the Apache configuration. I tried to test out each solution one by one, but I couldn't get anything working.

Here is what my admin site looks like right now

[image]

I'm also having a weird case where ***any*** subdomain works on my server. For example I was trying to set up my server so that http://www.satoshi.example.com/ would allow my normal (non-Django) content, while http://django.satoshi.example.com/ would allow my Django content to be served. But currently any subdomain, whether satoshi.example.com or blahblahasdas.satoshi.example.com is serving my Django files (I know because I can go to the `/admin` page on both site, although they will be in different sessions).

Anyway here are my files on the server which is running `CentOS` (not sure which version), `Apache 2.2.15`, `Python 2.6.6`, `django 1.3.1`, and `mod_wsgi 3.2`.

I will post what I think is the most relevant files and configuration below:

Apache throws these errors everytime I restart

```
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Wed Feb 29 00:45:36 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(140249420548064,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.6.2.
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.6.
[Wed Feb 29 01:45:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_auth_pgsql/2.0.3 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Here is `/var/www/html/mysite/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf` which gets loaded into my `httpd.conf` with the option `NameVirtualHost *:80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName django.satoshi.example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/django_error_log"

    WSGIDaemonProcess django
    WSGIProcessGroup django

    Alias /media/ "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media"
    <Directory "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes
        Allow from all
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes
        Allow from all
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/html/mysite/apache/django.wsgi"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/apache">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is `/var/www/html/mysite/apache/django.wsgi`

```
import os
import sys

paths = [
    '/var/www/html/mysite',
    '/var/www/html',
    '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/',
]

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And finally here is part of `/var/www/html/mysite/settings.py`

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files. 
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Let me know if you guys need any other files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excellent question. You've done your homework and provided plenty of information to work with. Keep it up.

Comment: Great question, I was also lost and adding ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to my setting file did the trick.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you should change:

```
Alias /media/ "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media"
```

to:

```
Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media"
```

Because you have:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Comment: That only applies to Django 1.4, which is not an official release yet (though it is dropping very soon). In Django 1.3, you *need* `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`. It won't work without it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I think he just needs to change his Alias to match is ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX after all.

Comment: Great! That worked perfect. Wow that was an easy solution that I overlooked... Later I'll have to do the standard thing and have something like lighthttpd handle static files. But that will be another question on another day :P. Thanks @jpic. You have helped me out before too :-).

Comment: Shouldn't 'Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media"' have a trailing '/'?

Comment: On Django 1.5 with Ubuntu 12.10 I had to use: "Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/"

Comment: Perfect answer!! Also thanks @aiham for this last detail on ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! Just a detail: If you also have the Alias /static/ for the general static files, be sure to include the Alias /static/admin/ before the general one.

Answer (score 18):

That's because you haven't setup your STATIC files...

Add to settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/'
```

Then run "python manage.py collectstatic"

That will put all the files under STATIC_ROOT which STATIC_URL will serve...  You shouldn't point Apache at your Python lib files!!

If you want your own app-specific static files as well, setup "STATICFILES_DIRS".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - collectstatic moves necessary files to your static dir and serves them from there.

Answer (score 3):

I got solution, I looked at the access_log files inside /var/log/httpd/

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2013:14:49:20 -0500] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 836 "http://127.0.0.1/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111109 CentOS/3.6.24-3.el6.centos Firefox/3.6.24"
```

so I added following tags in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file,

```
Alias /static /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

inside `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` tag

then I restarted service using

```
service httpd restart
```

and it **Works!!!**

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick for me. (Django 1.11 with Python 3.6)

```
Alias /static/admin /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin">
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   # AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Alias /static /var/www/app/static
```

Hope it helps.