# How to link static style files to Django app on Apache

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox, mod-wsgi

I'm in the process of setting up an Apache web server on an Ubuntu VM using Django with the intention of configuring it for production. I used [this walk-through](https://mindchasers.com/dev/apache-install) to get Apache and Django up and running, and since, I've been following along with the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/) provided in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/). I've gotten up to [Part 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial06/), which discusses managing static files, but I can't seem to get the styling to apply.

Abbreviated Server File Structure:

```
/etc/
--apache2/
----apache2.conf
....
/build/
--django/ <-- Django installation
--tstdj/ <-- target project
----manage.py
----polls/
------...
------static/
--------polls
----------styles.css
------templates/
----------....
----------index.html
------urls.py
------views.py
----static/
------....
------polls/
--------styles.css
----tstdj/
------....
------settings.py
------urls.py
------wsgi.py
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
....
WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/build/tstdj
WSGIProcessGroup www-data
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /build/tstdj/tstdj/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ /build/tstdj/static

<Directory /build/tstdj/tstdj>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 <Directory /build/tstdj/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/build/tstdj/tstdj/settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

....

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        '/build/tstdj/polls/static',
]

#STATIC_DIRS = 'static'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

/build/tstdj/polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
{% load static %}

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/styles.css' %}">

 <p><span>My name Jeff</span></p>

 {% if latest_question_list %}
     <ul>
     {% for question in latest_question_list %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.        question_text }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
 {% else %}
     <p>No polls are available.</p>
 {% endif %}
```

/build/tstdj/polls/static/polls/styles.css:

```
li a {
     color: green;
 }
```

Obviously, the desired output in this case is to have green links. The network tab of the inspector shows 403 errors on the styles.css file, as does attempting to go straight to `localhost:8080/static/`.

I've run `python manage.py collectstatic` and `sudo service apache2 restart` Lord knows how many times. I know there are means of getting the styling to work in development, but I've yet to get them functional for production.

Comment: 403 means that the access is forbidden. Did you check permissions on your static files?

Comment: @hendrikschneider I set the directory to "Require all granted" in apache2.conf. If I should be doing so elsewhere, I have no idea where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I attempting to change permissions in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` rather than `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

[Apache 403 while serving Django static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985342/apache-403-while-serving-django-static-files#24061418)