# Apache not serving admin static files for django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Before asking my question, I understand that there's a highly rated question about the same issue:[Apache not serving django admin static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500598/apache-not-serving-django-admin-static-files)

However, I've tried the same solution as can be seen below
This is my apache conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/sportsgullyrest/SportsGullyRest/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/sportsgullyrest/venv/bin/python2.7

Alias /static/admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/sportsgullyrest/static/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/sportsgullyrest/SportsGullyRest>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/sportsgullyrest/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

I'm using Django 1.7 and here is my settings file

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   ...
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
)
# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        ...
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = None

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/img/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a STATIC_ROOT setting, something like `os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'staticfiles')`.

Then, remove the `/static/admin/` alias from your Apache conf, make sure that the `static` alias is pointing to the staticfiles directory, and run `./manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: There's only one more error I'm facing. It seems like my main static files didn't get collected using `collectstatic`. So now Django static files are served but my front end static assets aren't found because they don't exist in the newly created staticfiles folder

Comment: So your STATICFILES_DIRS does need to include what you've called STATIC_PATH, I was wrong about that before (I was briefly confused because you'd defined that instead of STATIC_ROOT: the _PATH one is not a standard Django setting).