# Django deployed with Apache on Ubuntu loses all its styling

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to deploy a Django based product on an Ubuntu server with Apache. Everything goes well so far, and I can get de applications served by Apache, but I find that these applications lose all their styling.

This is the first time I do this, so I made some research and found and followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) that is pretty good, but I haven't found any reference to the problem I am having.

This is in my `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS    = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'FrontEndApp','public'),)
STATIC_URL          = '/res/'
STATIC_ROOT         = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

And this is my `000-default.conf`:

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


Alias /static /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/static
<Directory /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/Intellibook>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess Intellibook python-home=/home/axel/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv python-path=/home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook
WSGIProcessGroup Intellibook
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/Intellibook/wsgi.py
```

I made the test serving the applications with `pyhton manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, and everything worked perfectly. The problem exists only when the applications are served with Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be losing your static references.  When you access the app in a browser, right-click and choose `inspect` or `view page source`. Inside `inspect`, you should be able to see "Sources" and your CSS should show up on that list.  **This will tell you whether you are referencing the correct filepath or not.**

If you are not referencing the correct filepath, change `Alias /static /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/static` in `000-default.conf` to reflect the correct static references.

Comment: See also another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500598/apache-not-serving-django-admin-static-files

Comment: That was it. I found the problem. Thanks a lot!